# How to display the app name in a local notification in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, notifications, xamarin.android

I have an app with a [local notification](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications/). The problem is that it displays the "Project name" that comes from Visual Studio (see the screenshot). I would like the app to display something I can specify (the application name).

[[image: 2]]

The code to build the notification you see above is :

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

// Build the notification:
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked")
    .SetNumber(count)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click)
    .SetContentText(String.Format("The button has been clicked {0} times.", count));

// Finally, publish the notification:
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemServiceContext.NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());
```

I'm testing with Android 7.0 and it seems like the local notification documentation does not show anything about this "new" way of displaying a notification. I am able to change the small icon though.

I could not find anything on Xamarin forums or Google about that problem. I truly doubt people want to see the Visual Studio's project name there.

I even downloaded the [local notification sample project](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/LocalNotifications/) and it shows the project name.

Is it a limitation or am I missing something ? It seems to me like something too important to be a limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the Android application's `android:label` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, known as the "Application name" in the Xamarin.Android project settings.

[image]

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
~~~~
<application android:label="StackoverFlow" ~~~
~~~~
```

#### Output:

[image]

**Note:** Instead of setting this directly in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can also use an assembly level `ApplicationAttribute`:

```
[assembly: Application(Icon = "@drawable/Icon", Label = "StackOverflow")]
```

FYI: Xamarin's project template creates this Application attribute in `AssemblyInfo.cs` with an Icon parameter